# Typeorm: insert with foreign key when cascade enabled - not working

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I have 2 entities with a ManyToOne/OneToMany Relation with cascade enabled.

< One: Sender ---- Many: Transfer (cascade insert) >

I would like to insert 2 Transfers with the same sender but I'm getting an error that the uniqueness constraint of the sender address is being violated on the second insert.

```
@Entity()
export class Transfer extends BaseEntity {
  // Each transfer has an id and the sender
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Sender, (sender) => sender.sends, { 
      nullable: false, 
      eager: true, 
      cascade: ["insert"] })
  sender!: Sender
}

@Entity()
export class Sender extends BaseEntity {
  // Each address has an id and a value of the address
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @Column({ unique: true, nullable: false })
  address!: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Transfer, (transfer) => transfer.sender, { 
      eager: false, 
      cascade: false })
  sends!: Transfer[]
}
```

```
// get typeorm EntityManager
const em = dataSource.manager

const a = 'test_address'

// save the first transfer - cascade will also insert the sender
await em.save(Transfer, { sender: { address: a}})

// save a new transfer by the same sender
const s = await em.findOneBy(Sender, { address: a })
await em.save(Transfer, { sender: s })
```

How can I insert a new transfer without triggering an insert of a new sender if the sender already exists?

Comment: So after a lot of debugging I figured out that this code works just fine and the problem was coming from a different part of the code

Answer (score 2):

A few points:

1. You can set the eager: true on one side of the relationship only.
2. The problem here is that if the `sender` is not the primary key, how should `TypeOrm` know at all that we are referencing the same sender? It just cannot tell, hence it produces a new entry (which is wrongly called "`duplicate`"). The solution I would recommend is using the unique value (in this case, the sender) as a primary key.
3. Cascade insert here means if there is a new Sender instance set on this relation, it will be inserted automatically to the db when you save this transfer entity

```
    @ManyToOne(() => Sender, (sender) => sender.sends, { 
          nullable: false, 
          eager: true, 
          cascade: ["insert"] })
      sender!: Sender
```

4. Try doing this:

```
 @OneToMany(() => Transfer, (transfer) => transfer.sender)
      sends!: Transfer[]
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what's happening is when the second `Transfer` gets created, TypeORM tries to insert a new `Sender` with the same address as the existing sender and that then conflicts with your `Sender.address` unique string constraint:

```
  @Column({ unique: true, nullable: false })
  address!: string;
```

TypeOrm Insert does not check if the object exists, it's the unique flag for `Sender.address` that is checking uniqueness.

TypeORM Upsert is used to check if the object exists and do an insert, although I don't see a way to use that in the same way you've done a cascade insert: `cascade: ["insert"] })`. See some docs from https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/relations

> cascade: boolean | ("insert" | "update")[] - If set to true, the
> related object will be inserted and updated in the database. You can
> also specify an array of cascade options.

It worries me that there's an open issue for cascade inserts on TypeOrm Github (example uses `User` / `Color` entities, where `Color` is uniquely identified by a string; similar to your `Sender.address`)
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/7171

So I suggest two options:

1. Remove `cascade: ["insert"]` from `Sender.entity` and on `Transfer.save`, have additional logic to create the sender if it does not already exist. You could use subscribers to listen for `Transfer` insertions (within `Transfer` entity) and implement logic there to insert a `Sender`: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/listeners-and-subscribers.md -
2. Ask the question on TypeOrm Github (use above issue link) to see if there's a better workaround.